# How to "shift-click" select many files at once in android (range select)

Tags: file-management, open-source, optimization

How can I select a range of files in Android?

I'm trying to use Amaze File Manager to create a compressed archive of ~200 files in a directory of ~2,000 files. All the files I want to select are in one continuous sequence.

In my linux file manager (eg thunar or nautilus) I would simple select the first file, hold the shift key, and select the last file. That's two clicks and one key press.

In my android file manager (Amaze), I have to tap 200 times.

Is there any open-source file manager in android that will let me select N continuous files with less than 5 taps?

Comment: See also https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager/issues/2070

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [MiXplorer Silver File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixplorer.silver&hl=en_US&gl=US). Select the first file, then the last. Everything in between will be selected.